# Magento 2 Updating Other Products in catalog_product_save_after event Observer

Tags: magento2, php, collection, custom-attributes

I had created an Observer of this event:`catalog_product_save_after`
I am trying to update other products and loading them on the basis of their id, but it is giving me an error. I am Sharing my code here.

Code:-

```
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
    $brand = $product->getBrand();
    $model = $product->getModel();

    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('model', $model);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('brand', $brand);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
    $collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC');

    $i = 0;
    $prodId = [];
    foreach ($collection as $value) {
        if($i != 0) {
            $prodId[] = $value->getId();
        }
        $i++;
    }
    foreach($prodId as $mypro) {
        $productRepository = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($mypro);
        $productRepository->setData('best_price', 0);
        $productRepository->save();
    }
```

**What I Tried:-**
I tried to save one product first without using foreach loop but it also gave the same error.
I tried to do it by this as well, but received the same error:-

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($collection as $value) {
if($i != 0) {
$prodId = $value->getId();
$productRepository = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($prodId);
                $productRepository->setData('best_price', 0);
                $productRepository->save();
}
$i++;
}
```

**Error:**

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `attribute_set_id` = ?, `type_id` = ?, `sku` = ?, `has_options` = ?, `required_options` = ?, `created_at` = ?, `updated_at` = ? WHERE (entity_id = '5263')

**Expected Result:**
I wanted to **save my custom attribute of other's product** when one product is saved.

Please help me. I am trying to fix it from a couple of hours but didn't solve. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use saveAttribute() method to save custom attribute

```
$productRepository=$objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$product =$productRepository->getById($mypro);
$product->setBestPrice(0);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'best_price');
```

**Note:  Code Tested**

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, it is not working..

Comment: Error:    Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor::save(), 0 passed in Observer/CatalogProductSaveAfterObserver.php on line 109 and at least 1 expected in /Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository/Interceptor.php:20

Comment: clear generated then try ....rm -rf var/cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ generated/

Comment: I tried it by cleaning cache and generated 
and I runned all the commands and then checked, and it gived above mentioned error:- ArgumentCountError

Comment: Try my updated code

Comment: It worked, thankyou. :)

Comment: I accepted, and give 1 + point. thankyou.

Comment: getResource method is deprecated, but it worked like a charm